How to enumerate all Documents/tabs of a DockPanel?
This is using DockPanelSuite in winforms.
I have a DockPanel dockMain with many tabs on it, including FloatWindows. I have a function that is supposed to check if a tab exists with a certain name, and if found, Activate it.
private void FindTab(string tabname)
{
   if (dockMain.Documents.Where(x => x.DockHandler.TabText == tabname)).Any())
      dockMain.Documents.Where(x => x.DockHandler.TabText == tabname)).First().DockHandler.Activate();
}

However, dockMain.Documents seems to only find non-float documents so it never finds a tab that is floating even if the name does exist.
I checked over all the methods of dockMain.FloatWindows too but there doesn't seem to be a simple way to get the tabs open in each of them.

There are relationships between all the windows in an application (a combination of owner ship and parent hood). If you get the Spy++ tool (which I think is now get-table as a C++ add on to Visual Studio), you can manually inspection these relationships. Once you manually figure out the relationships in you app, you can the traverse the window graph
